# Do neutrons exhibit momentary small charges due to the movement of its quarks?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, neutrons, dipole, multipole-expansion

So in a similar way to electrons moving in atoms, causing induced dipole-dipole interactions, can neutrons momentarily attract or repel?

Comment: I guess a related question would be: does a neutron have higher multipole moments?

Comment: @Javier You're correct that the question of higher moments is related, but it's easier to answer. The [Wigner-Eckart theorem proves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243735/44126) that, as a spin-1/2 system, the neutron may carry monopole and dipole moments but no higher.

Comment: related: [Does a neutral particle feel the electric pull?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317980/84967), [Is there any way to attract or repel neutrons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302570/84967).

Comment: A recent paper, which I might turn into an answer later:  Babb, Higa, & Hussein, [Dipole-dipole dispersion interactions between neutrons,](http://inspirehep.net/record/1501980?ln=en) Eur. Phys. J. A53 (2017) no.6, 126.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that within the standard model of particle physics

> [*A permanent electric dipole moment of a fundamental particle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_electric_dipole_moment) violates both parity (P) and time reversal symmetry (T). These violations can be understood by examining the neutron's magnetic dipole moment and hypothetical electric dipole moment. Under time reversal, the magnetic dipole moment changes its direction, whereas the electric dipole moment stays unchanged. Under parity, the electric dipole moment changes its direction but not the magnetic dipole moment. As the resulting system under P and T is not symmetric with respect to the initial system, these symmetries are violated in the case of the existence of an EDM. Having also CPT symmetry, the combined symmetry CP is violated as well.

Thus experiments trying for new physics beyond the standard model have tried to measure it for the neutron:

> The neutron electric dipole moment (nEDM) i*s a measure for the distribution of positive and negative charge inside the neutron.* A finite electric dipole moment can only exist if the centers of the negative and positive charge distribution inside the particle do not coincide. So far, no neutron EDM has been found. The [current best upper limit](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.04411) amounts to |dn| $< 3.0×10^−26 e⋅cm.$

As CP violation has been observed in particle data,  to a very small amount, the value  due to CP violation for the electric dipole moment of the neutron is expected to be around $ 10^−31 e⋅cm$, way smaller than the present limit.

> can neutrons momentarily attract or repel?

Do not forget that the neutrons are in the realm of strong interactions , and will attract other neutrons or protons, in orders of magnitude stronger reaction. The technique for the electric dipole  measurement is [described here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0602020)

Comment: but OP is asking about non-permanent dipole interactions, like London dispersion force

Comment: @DavePhD the standard model does not allow either permanent or instantaneous  violation. Beyond the standard model , as the CP violation number  shows, the effect should be equally very small, afaik. It is a moot point since quarks are a soup of strongly interacting gluons and quark antiquark pairs within the neutron , cannot be compared with orbitals in molecules and atoms. Will need lattice QCD for calculations.

Comment: Stationary states can not have electric dipole moments, but time dependent states can.  http://robotics.cs.tamu.edu/dshell/cs689/papers/anderson72more_is_different.pdf

Comment: Since a neutron is not a fundamental particle in the Standard Model, is the first quote on point?

Comment: @HenningMakholm   , it should say "quanrum mechanical entitites"  I guess. CP violation in  hadrons  , it is not simple :  https://www.ncnr.nist.gov/summerschool/ss09/pdf/Filippone_FP09.pdf

Comment: @DavePhD  The analysis I have seen need time or CP violation to do this, i.e. outside the standard model. Do you have a link that disputes this? After all the standard model is not a la cart, instantaneous or averaged? It should hold for all (x,y,z,t)?  The London dispersion forces do not appear for a single atom, but for a quantum mechanical system of two atoms where there are large distances within  the charge densities of the individual atoms. This is not true for two neutrons  with their complicated quark content .  ( form factor analysis does show radial distributions of charges).

Comment: See  https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.2409.pdf

Comment: In your link, the argument is based on laws of motion, the  hadronic stationary states are not governed by laws of motion,  in this case complicated QCD cannot be approximated as far as instantaneous differences go, the way it can be done with atoms.